# How can i add a picture from the server to File Image field of drupal 7?

Tags: javascript, image, webcam, drupal-7

I need to add the image from webcam to image field on drupal 7 node creation page. I have already the procedure, which stores the image from webcam to the server. Now, how can I show it in image field of create node form?

I need it, so the user can delete/move it and then save the node.

I've found this module http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources but I don't really understand how could it help me...

Answer (score 0):

I gather you're trying to let the user select the image for the form.  To accomplish this, you're not going to be able to use a standard `<input type="file">` field, because due to browser security, you're not allowed to access that field and populate it, or anything.

So, instead, you're going to have to either

1. Use a `select` control which lists the images the user is allowed to choose from
2. Build your own file selection tool which behaves similarly to the `<input type="file">` control.  There's a lot of ways you could go about this, an example of one would be: use an uneditable textbox (`<input type="text" disabled>`), faux browse button (`<button>Browse</button>`), and use a modal that shows previews of available images which the user can click to select.
3. Some other custom solution for letting the user choose a file

It shouldn't really be too bad/hard to accomplish, just involves writing more code since you can't use the native file browser.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'd like to automatically call 'upload' button in image field after the image is being written by my php script on the server and then really "upload" image into drupal. Then image should appear in image field like normal uploaded images.

Comment: @EugenA - I don't know that I understand your last comment, can you try to clarify?

Comment: on the node creation page the user can add pictures to node using two ways: a) upload it or b) snap a picture from webcam.
On the same page there is a webcam area with live view from the webcam. So, user click on "snap picture" and picture goes to the server.
The problem is - these pictures from the webcam are not stored into the same field as normal uploaded pictures. I'd like to put them immediatly after clicking on "snap a pic" button into image field.